# Using tkinter and avoiding import in every file but how?

Tags: python, tkinter, import, interface

I am creating a program with a gui and I want to treat the single items in the gui as objects. Now I am struggling with the `import tkinter as tk` because I do not want to `import` it in every single file.

I already tried to use the `import` statement in different `__init__.py` files, in `def __init__(self):` function and I also tried to pass the `tk.Tk()` object as an parameter through the whole structure that you see here:

```
root
|- __main__.py
|- __init__.py
|- gui
   |- gui.py
   |- __init__.py
   |- frames
      |- frame.py
      |- __init__.py
      |- singleframe
         |- topbarframe.py
         |- mainmenuframe.py
         |- __init__.py
```

Only passing the object `tk.Tk()` worked but also crashed when I was trying to use the `Frame()` statement because `tk.Tk() has no attribute Frame...` because I always get that I have no reference to `Frame()` when I do not `import tkinter` in every single file.

How I am supposed to `import tkinter` just **once** in the "Main_level" file/area so that the directories (and subdirectories) are able to use all functionalities? *New in Python but still have not figured it out after reading several blogs "How To"s.*

Comment: You will have to `import tkinter` in every script you have that uses it. The result from the first time it happens is automatically cached so subsequent `import`s are extremely quick.

Comment: Ok, I thought about a solutions that looks a little bit prettier than having the `import` in every script. But ok if I have to do so I will do it, thank you.